# java, not conecting with sql server

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse

I have two computers, they have the same windows, same versions of java, everything the same, but in one the code works and in the other it doesnt.
I dont know if its fault of the code or im doing something wrong setting up one of the computers.
I need you to help me see if the code is fine.

```
    try
    {
        txtBDUrl.setEnabled(false);
        txtPassword.setEnabled(false);
        txtUser.setEnabled(false);

        if(txtBDUrl.getText().length() > 0)
        {
            Map properties = new HashMap();

            String pass = txtPassword.getText();
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", txtBDUrl.getText());

            if (cboDBDriver.getSelectedIndex() ==2)
            {
                properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                selectedDriver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
            }

            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password",pass);
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", txtUser.getText());

            entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PrescricaoReceitasPU",properties);

            EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();


            if(entityManager.isOpen())
            {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),
                    "Foi possível conectar à base de dados com sucesso",
                    "Configuração",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

               btnConfirmar.setEnabled(true);
            }else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),
                    "Não foi possível conectar à base de dados",
                    "Configuração",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                btnConfirmar.setEnabled(false);
                return;
            }

        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),
                    "Não foi possível conectar à base de dados",
                    "Configuração",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        Logger.getLogger(PrescricaoReceitasApp.LogName).log(Level.INFO, ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        txtBDUrl.setEnabled(true);
        txtPassword.setEnabled(true);
        txtUser.setEnabled(true);
    }
}//GEN-LAST:event_btnTestConnectionActionPerformed
```

**EDIT** : Here is the error console from OP :

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 192.168.x.x, port x has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
Error Code: 0
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 192.168.x.x, port x has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getServerSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:195)
    at prescricaoreceitas.AdminTools.DBConnectionDialogView.btnTestConnectionActionPerformed(DBConnectionDialogView.java:296)
    at prescricaoreceitas.AdminTools.DBConnectionDialogView.access$0(DBConnectionDialogView.java:260)
    at prescricaoreceitas.AdminTools.DBConnectionDialogView$1.actionPerformed(DBConnectionDialogView.java:121)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at prescricaoreceitas.INFOReceitasMainView.formComponentShown(INFOReceitasMainView.java:1372)
    at prescricaoreceitas.INFOReceitasMainView.access$12(INFOReceitasMainView.java:1314)
    at prescricaoreceitas.INFOReceitasMainView$8.componentShown(INFOReceitasMainView.java:670)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.componentShown(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processComponentEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 192.168.x.x, port x has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:369)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 192.168.x.x, port x has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:187)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:238)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2197)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:446)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1338)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1022)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:858)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:98)
    ... 83 more
```

Comment: Don't you have LogFile or Error in console to help us?

Comment: It doesnt give any error it just says it wasnt possible to conect with database

Comment: It is an error! Can you please show us the message?

Comment: is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes already checked that

Comment: Good. Are you sure that both computers have rights to access to server and network? (Port, IPs, Firewall, ...)

Comment: Yes already checked that

Comment: As far as I recall, you would need to install a seperate driver. Could it be that on one machine it was installed but not on the other?

Comment: Wich driver? Of what program??

Comment: @MiguelBoavida: Please take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) link. You will need to install the connector that allows you to connect to an MS SQL Database.

Comment: im going to check it thx

Comment: `Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 192.168.x.x, port x has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
`  It is a networking error.  Is the DB server on a 3rd machine? From the machine that doesn't work, can you connect to the SQL server in other ways?

Comment: yes i can connect to the sql server in other ways